# Add values in MATLAB matrix based on pairs

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, addition

Apologies if something similar has been asked before. It seems like it should be an easy problem on the face of it, but I'm having trouble describing this -- let alone solving it! Let's suppose I have a single 5 x 3 matrix that looks something like this:

```
A = [50  1  2
     75  2  3 
     20  2  3
     10  1  1
     90  1  2]
```

I want to sum the values in the first column wherever there is a pair in the 2nd and 3rd column that is duplicated somewhere else. So, I'm trying to transform A (above) into something like this 3 x 3 matrix B, where:

```
    B = [140  1  2
         95   2  3 
         10   1  1]
```

Just the values from column 1 get added, and I need them to stay matched to the pair that "caused" them to combine. I guess I should also add that the order of values in columns 2 & 3 does matter in that 3,4 counts as a different pair than 4,3. (Of course my actual data include values in columns 2 & 3 that range well into the 100s, so writing an if statement for each possible combination isn't really a possibility...)

Any suggestions for this would be much appreciated! I was studying the documentation on 'find' and stumbled across something called 'ismember' -- do I need to be using some application of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) - [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) couple is suited for the job:

```
[u, ~, v] = unique(A(:,2:end), 'rows', 'stable');
B = [accumarray(v, A(:,1)) u];
```

Comment: Damn, now you didn't even wait for me to post an inefficient solution:D Nice job! Again I looked at `help accumarray` to no avail Maybe I should leave these questions to you in the first place;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak This is idiomatic `accumarray` use. You'll learn to love it :-)

Comment: I'm not sure...it's pretty alien to me every time I see it:) Just doesn't fit my way of thinking. But I rarely need to do such things, so it's OK:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak You already use `bsxfun`... `accumarray` wil be the next step :-D